# how to install specific version of Ruby in Arch-Based Linux

Tags: manjaro, ruby

I was trying to install specific version Ruby in Manjaro. I had tried some query.

```bsh
sudo pacman -Sy ruby:2.6.6
sudo pacman -Sy ruby-2.6.6
```

Both of them returning `target not found`. I was reading [the thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245606). But, Some people said that pacman doesn't allow to install specific version. How can I install specific version of Ruby then? Current Ruby version is 3.0.1. But, I need 2.6.6. So, I must have to install that version of Ruby.

I had installed 2.6.6 following way.

```bsh
sudo rvm install 2.6.6
```

When I tried to use it

```
sudo rvm use 2.6.6
sudo rvm use 2.6.6 --default
```

I got following error

> RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
> you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/istiak/qpixel/Gemfile'.
> To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
> Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
> Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RVM

Comment: @muru If I try `rvm install 2.6.6` Will it work then?